# Is there a way to detect with invisible recaptcha if the user is possibly a bot?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, captcha, invisible-recaptcha

I need to perform a task on the client only if the user is likely not a bot. It has to be completely automatic, so I don't want to show a captcha to the user to actually do the verification, I just want to know if the user is most likely not a bot.

This could be done with invisible recaptca which shows the captcha only if it thinks the user is a bot. Unfortunately, it looks like it only has a success callback if the verification is passed (either automatically and manually).

Is there some way to use only the invisible part of recaptcha, that is to get the information if the user is suspected to be a bot or not?

**Edit: I know how invisible recpatcha works, I use it. It shows a captcha if it thinks the user is suspicious. I don't want it to show a captcha in this case, I want it to call a callback function of mine instead (e.g userIsSuspicious())**

Comment: sorry, you do ask for Google reCaptcha servise, right?

Comment: yes, recaptcha is google's service

Answer (score 0):

sure there is,, when you login to your Google reCaptcha account, in the process of creating new client site choose the invisible option, like this:

[image]

Comment: I know that. The question is about using invisible recpatcha to detect if the user is a possible bot **without** showing the actual captcha if google thinks the user is suspicious and returing to me only this "suspiciousness" information about the user.